# Flow seems to assume wrong type while iterating over Object.entries

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

EDIT: since this seems to be a bug, I've opened an issue on Github [#4997](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/4997)

In the following example, Flow seems to assume that `label` is of type `mixed` even though both the Props declaration, and the anonymous function declaration bind it to `Node`. What am I missing?

```
/* @flow */
import React from 'react';
import type { Node } from 'react';

type Props = {
  values: { [string]: Node },
  /* … */
};

export default class SelectButtons extends React.Component<Props> {
  /* … */

    createButtons(): Array<Node> {
    return Object.entries(this.props.values).map(
      ([value: string, label: Node], index: number): Node => (
        <button>
          {label}
        </button>
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the error message:

```
             v------
 44:         <button
 45:           onClick={() => this.choose(value)}
 46:           key={index}
 47:           className={this.block('option', { selected: value === this.state.value })()}
 48:         >
             ^ React element `button`
             v------
 44:         <button
 45:           onClick={() => this.choose(value)}
 46:           key={index}
 47:           className={this.block('option', { selected: value === this.state.value })()}
 48:         >
             ^ React element `button`. This type is incompatible with
                v
170:     props: {
171:       children?: React$Node,
172:       [key: string]: any,
173:     },
         ^ object type. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react-dom.js:170
  Property `children` is incompatible:
     49:           {label}
                    ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
    171:       children?: React$Node,
                          ^^^^^^^^^^ union: undefined | null | boolean | number | string | type application of type `React$Element` | type application of identifier `Iterable`. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react-dom.js:171
      Member 1:
       15:   | void
               ^^^^ undefined. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:15
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       15:   | void
               ^^^^ undefined. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:15
      Member 2:
       16:   | null
               ^^^^ null. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:16
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       16:   | null
               ^^^^ null. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:16
      Member 3:
       17:   | boolean
               ^^^^^^^ boolean. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:17
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       17:   | boolean
               ^^^^^^^ boolean. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:17
      Member 4:
       18:   | number
               ^^^^^^ number. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:18
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       18:   | number
               ^^^^^^ number. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:18
      Member 5:
       19:   | string
               ^^^^^^ string. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:19
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       19:   | string
               ^^^^^^ string. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:19
      Member 6:
       20:   | React$Element<any>
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of type `React$Element`. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:20
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. Inexact type is incompatible with exact type
       20:   | React$Element<any>
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ exact type: object type. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:20
      Member 7:
       21:   | Iterable<React$Node>;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ type application of identifier `Iterable`. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:21
      Error:
       49:           {label}
                      ^^^^^ mixed. This type is incompatible with
       21:   | Iterable<React$Node>;
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ $Iterable. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:21
        Property `@@iterator` is incompatible:
           21:   | Iterable<React$Node>;
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ property `@@iterator` of $Iterable. Property not found in. See lib: /tmp/flow/flowlib_3bead812/react.js:21
           49:           {label}
                          ^^^^^ mixed
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now, I'm assuming that it is a bug. If you think I'm wrong, and have a better answer, please feel free to answer, and I will accept it gladly!

I assume it is a bug because of the following workaround:

```
createButtons(): Array<Node> {
  return Object.keys(this.props.values).map((value: string, index: number): Node => (
    <button>
      {this.props.values[value]}
    </button>
  ));
}
```

By referencing the object directly, instead of iterating over it with `Object.entries`, flow now assumes the correct type.

EDIT: As I've given this a bit more thought, the problem lies in the typing of arrays, and the fact that arrays in Flow can carry only one type for their elements.

The callback argument of `Object.entries()` is of type `Array<mixed> => void`. An ideal type for it would be `Array<[K, V]> => void`, where `K` and `V` are the objects' key and value types, respectively (`K` is always `string`, I think.)

This would require heterogeneous collections, where `Array<[K, V]>` is inhabited by all length-2 arrays whose first element is of type `K` and the second of type `V`. This would likely require some type-level operators and higher-kinded types that Flow is (currently) unable to provide.

The workaround using `Object.keys` works, because `Object.keys` doesn't need heterogeneous arrays (all keys are of the same type) but it might fail if your object doesn't look like `{ [string]: X }`, but instead has values of different types (say `{ foo: number, bar: string }`, making it (again) a heterogeneous collection.